# Steam app data files using twice the expected disk space on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: macos, filesystem, disk-space, steam

My son wanted a game from steam, which said it required 40GiB disk space. Sure, done. Installed, but I noticed it was using 80GiB disk space, but didn't think much of it, until it decided to auto-patch and ran out of disk space.

Digging into the install, there's a single file, as reported by the Finder & ls, that is ~37GiB in size. It is using ~75GiB disk space according to the Finder and du.

```
sh$ pwd
/Users/zz/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Tropico 6/Tropico6.app/Contents/UE4/Tropico6/Content/Paks
sh$ ls -l pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zz  staff  40001130623 31 Mar 17:12 pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
sh$ du -k pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak 
78127216        pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
sh$ ls -lh pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zz  staff    37G 31 Mar 17:12 pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
sh$ du -h pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
 75G    pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak
```

[image: Finder file info]

Searching around, I see mention of timemachine snapshots (`tmutil listlocalsnapshots` shows none), sparse files (no, they generally show the opposite, large eof and small usage), APFS compression (`stat -f %f pakchunk0-MacNoEditor.pak` returns zero, and `afscexpand` does nothing).

What could this be? A bad `fallocate(2)` by steam (does Mac OS X even have that)? A copy of the file in another logical fork? Multiple write heads leading to some weird internal fragmentation? Something else? What weird thing has Apple managed to do this time?

So, the question is, what could possibly cause a 40GB file to require 80GB on Mac OS X? Is this an APFS bug?

PS: fwiw, a Duplicate+Delete+Rename in the Finder fixed this one file (ie. released 40GB disk space), and I assume thanks to the APFS clone functionality, did so without copying any data. And on a second attempt, I noticed that **just doing the duplicate** released the space.

Comment: This got a bit unclear with the update. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: What could cause a 40GB file to occupy 80GB? Is this a bug in the OS? Is it Steam doing something crazy? I've never seen this behaviour under NetBSD, Linux, OpenVMS, AIX, Solaris, etc, etc, so what is Mac OS X doing here?

Comment: Do you share macOS user accounts with your son or do each of you have your own separate logins? Were either of you required to enter an administrator password at any point during installation?

Comment: Separate logins, my login is an Admin. Steam has only been run under his login, and at no point during the installation was Admin requested.

Comment: @PaulRipke Can you re-run your `du` invocations under `sudo` and see if that changes the size?

Comment: I believe I did run them under my son's account and via sudo - no difference found. I'd be very concerned if there was a difference - Apple would have to be doing something very strange indeed. From my last foray into xnu, that piece of the kernel is pretty BSDish.